# Integral with exponential approximated by a dirac function

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, dirac-delta

So, I have the following integral : 
$$I = \int_0^t e^{-a(t-t')}f(t') dt'$$

If $a > 0$ is large enough, I know you can approximate the exponential by a dirac function, which gives $e^{-a(t-t')} \sim \frac{\delta(t-t')}{a}$, and the integral becomes $I = \frac{f(t)}{a}$.

However, this development is quite strong, and does not apply if $a$ is not that large. The question is, is there a better development at higher order for such integrals ?

I should add that we know almost nothing of $f$, except that it's continuous, and is at least $C^1$.

Comment: I assume it should be $e^{-a|t-t'|}$ and $I = \frac{f(t)}{a}$.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, I inverted $t$ and $t'$. I corrected it.

Comment: It's not the inversion. It is the absolute value in the exponent.

Comment: Oh, right. Does it matter that much ? Since we always have $t' < t$ in the integration, then $a(t-t')$ is always positive, and the exponential will be almost null except when $t' \simeq t$ ?

Comment: It's  ok as you wrote it.  But you said "you can approximate the exponential by a dirac function," which in general holds only for the exponential with absolute exponent.

Answer (score 1):

One option you certainly have, that is frequently employed by physicists, is to write the exponential $\exp(-a(t^\prime - t))$ as a Taylor-series and cut off lower order terms. Say you would just keep the first two or so. In many cases that will give you a reasonable approximation of the integral.

Alternatively, since $f$ is continuous you could have as a very rough estimate:
$$ \int_0^t \exp(-a(t-s))f(s)\mathrm{d}s \le \frac{1 - exp(-at)}{a}\|f\|_\infty$$

where $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{s \in [0,t]} f(s)$.

Comment: Of course, but it implies I know the expression of the function $f$ to calculate the integral, which I do not. There would still be an integral.

Comment: @Tinta I've updated my answer with an alternative.